# Nearest Neighbor Heuristic

Tags: graph-algorithm

I am teaching myself on TSP using a textbook.
I am confused on the difference between Nearest Neighbor Heuristic and Smallest Increase Heuristic.

As it is described in my text book, I have the following as the definition of each.

**Nearest neighbor heuristic:** Read in the next point, and add it to the current tour after the point to which it is closest.
If there is more than one point to which it is closest, insert it after the first such point you discover.

**Smallest increase heuristic:** Read in the next point, and add it to the current tour after the point where it results in
the least possible increase in the tour length. If there is more than one point, insert it after the first such point you
discover.

For the second heuristic, wouldn't the closest point give you the smallest increase in the total distance? So what is exactly the difference between these two heuristics?

I would appreciate any input from you guys.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this description of Nearest Neighbor seems nonstandard. Usually, all the points are considered to be "read in" already and NN adds the point which is closest to the end of the growing tour. The book you are using seems to be constructing tours before all of the points are known, by inserting each new point into the growing tour.

Say the partial tour is `ABCDE` and `F` is the new point. This version of Nearest Neighbor inserts `F` after the point `P` which minimizes `d(P,F)`. Note that if this is e.g. `B` then the tour cost is increased by the *sum* `d(B,F) + d(F,C)`. Nearest Neighbor ignores the second term completely. The smallest increase heuristic takes it into consideration. It seeks to minimize the total cost of insertion and not just the first term.

Both algorithms would start with `AB`, where `A` and `B` are the first two points read. They would potentially diverge with `C` (the third point read). The Nearest Neighbor would extend the tour to either `ABC` or `ACB` depending on whether `d(A,C)` or `d(B,C)` is smaller. On the other hand, the smallest increase heuristic as described would look at `ACB` or `ABC`, depending on which is the shortest tour (which is equivalent to saying which one represents the least increase from the tour `AB`).

As I said earlier, this is a non-standard description of Nearest Neighbor, though it is certainly a reasonable heuristic. Also, it should be noted that the smallest-increase heuristic is not always better than the nearest neighbor as described here. This is since the smallest-increase heuristic might forgo good edges for reasons that are essentially irrelevant in the final tour. If `AC` is a good edge why bypass it just because `CB` is a bad edge when `CB` is unlikely to be an edge in the final tour?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. However, I am still not clear on how this insertion works - let's say we start at a point A. Then, we find a point B closest from A (minimize d(A,B)) and start the algorithm again at B until every vertex is marked. (B would find a closest point C and so on). Wouldn't this result in the same tour for both heuristics? Am I misunderstanding the insertion process completely? Thank you for your time

Comment: @user3777839 See if the edited post addresses your question. By the way -- what text are you using?